# Malloc fails to allocate memory on atmega2561 and freeRTOS

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmel, freertos

I am trying to use the malloc() function to create nodes for a Linked List. The function in my case returns NULL on the following dummy segment of code.

I am running FREERTOS on an atmega 2561.

```
 if (!malloc(sizeof(struct Event))
    {
        //The code gets inside here
    } else {
        //
    }
```

The struct of the nodes is the following:

```
struct Event 
{
    uint8_t shouldCarBrake;
    uint16_t tachoPoint;
    struct Event *next;
};
```

Comment: I do not know atmega2561. Do you know if you have enough memory ?

Comment: Yes i do have i have checked it

Comment: Is there any reason why you check malloc for 0 and not the Pointer (if(!ptr){ /* ERROR */} which actually get the memory? I'm just asking.

Comment: this line: `if (!malloc(sizeof(struct Event))` would be much better written as: `if (NULL == (ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Event)) ) )`   As it is, no pointer variable is being set, so the posted code would result in a memory leak as the (non existent) pointer variable can not be passed to `free(0`

Comment: @John : Checked it how?  That information should probably be in the question.  It is not just a matter of having free memory; that memory has to be allocated to the heap, and the heap itself must have a single contiguous block of memory to satisfy the allocation request (i.e. not be too fragmented to allocate, even when cumulatively there is enough memory).

Comment: Whose compiler and standard library implementation are you using?  Some libraries (such as [Newlib](http://www.billgatliff.com/newlib.html)) require stub implementation to support heap management, while others ([avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html)) may require configuration to your target.

Answer (score 2):

If the project is set up to use four out of the five example heap memory management files that come with FreeRTOS then it might be that the heap size supplied by the C libraries is zero.  Out of the 5 only heap_3 uses malloc.  See http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library `malloc()` is not normally thread-safe, so should probably not be used in this instance.  Some libraries provide stubs for mutex locks for the standard library, but if that is not the case or you choose not implement them, then `malloc()` itself should be wrapped in a function with mutex locks, or an alternative thread-safe heap management implementation used.  FreeRTOS provides both of these options as described [here](http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html).

The standard `malloc()` implementation is also non-deterministic - another reason not to use it in real-time critical code; you cannot determine how-long the mutex will be locked for, so not only will the thread allocating be non-deterministic, but so will any threads waiting to allocate.

Even without FreeRTOS's support for various allocators, it is easy to implement a deterministic fixed-block memory allocator in a manner that is easily portable to any RTOS. You simply pre-allocate a pool (or pools) of memory blocks (either statically or from the standard heap before real-time scheduling starts), and stuff an RTOS queue with pointers to the blocks.  Allocation is then simply a case taking a pointer from the queue, and deallocation by returning the pointer back to the queue.